# LINQ Join: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a list that are generated from Linq to SQL.  For simplicity it looks like this:

```
var myItems = (from my in db.MyTable
                select new
                {
                    UniqueID = my.ID,
                    UserName = my.UserName,
                    CreatedOn = my.CreatedOn
                }).ToList();
```

This list contains 4 items.

And I have another:

```
var grid = (from q in AnotherLinqQuery
                select new
                {
                    UniqueID = q.ID,
                    Department = q.Department,
                    Comments = q.Comments
                }).ToList();
```

This list contains 20 items.
All the ID's in myItems appear in grid.

Now I want to join it up with a left join.

```
var q = from A in grid
        from B in myItems.Where(x => x.UniqueID == grid.UniqueID).DefaultIfEmpty()
        select new 
        {
           UniqueID = A.UniqueID,
           Department = A.Department,
           CreatedOn = B.CreatedOn
        }
```

When I execute this, I get

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

I've also tried other joins such as

```
from A in grid
            from B in myItems.Where(x => x.UniqueID != null && x.UniqueID == grid.UniqueID).DefaultIfEmpty()
```

Comment: The exception is not from the `join` (actually you have no explicit join operator, but `SelectMany`), but from `select` clause - `B.CreatedOn` when `B` is `null`.

Comment: Thanks Ivan, you are right.  If I change my select to CreatedOn = B == null ?   null : B.CreatedOn then it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are doing a *left join* instead of an *inner join*, there will be no items from `myItems` for the 16 elements that are only in `grid` but not in `myItems`.

`B` will be `null` in that cases (as `DefaultIfEmpty()` creates a sequence with one `null` element), so you have to check for `null` here:

```
var q = from A in grid
        from B in myItems.Where(x => x.UniqueID == grid.UniqueID).DefaultIfEmpty()
        select new 
        {
           UniqueID = A.UniqueID,
           Department = A.Department,
           CreatedOn = B?.CreatedOn ?? DateTime.MinValue // or whatever default value you like
        }
```

Comment: Credit then to Rene, Ivan and Klaus.  This is the solution that works best for me so I'll accept this.

Answer (score 3):

You are not joining correctly. Try this:

```
var q = from A in grid
        join B in myItems on A.UniqueId equals B.UniqueId into LB
        from B in LB.DefaultIfEmpty()
        select new 
        {
            UniqueID = A.UniqueID,
            Department = A.Department,
            CreatedOn = B.CreatedOn
        };
```

You may want to refer to the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311040.aspx) for further info on joining in linq.

Comment: A join like this will create an inner join (i.e result will have 4 items).  I want to do a left join with a resulting 20 items, of which 4 should show a CreatedOn value.

Comment: Your logic makes sense. I currently get a error on the keyword "new": NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.  Will keep playing - I'm closer to a solution - thanks so far.